# Global variable in python function doesn't work for my code

Tags: python, variables, global

This works.

```
a = [2,5,3,7,9,12]
def mean_list(x):
      b = 0
      for i in x:
            b=b+i
            c = b/len(x)
      return c
print(mean_list(a))
```

but this doesn't work, even though I have declared my list as global. Why?

```
def mean_list(x):
      global a
      a = [2,5,3,7,9,12]
      b = 0
      for i in x:
            b=b+i
            c = b/len(x)
      return c
print(mean_list(a))
```

Comment: Define *"doesn't work"*. Why are you using global state anyway? And why are you passing the same thing as a parameter?

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"? Does it throw an Error? If so, add the complete traceback with the error. Before you call the function there is no `a` so you can't pass `a` into the function (because it does not exist).

Comment: In the second example you define the function which defines `a`. Then you try to call the function by passing `a` as a parameter. The problem is that `a` has not been defined yet because the function has not been called!

Comment: a is not defined, when you call global. create it outside of the function and it will work. But it is prettier to call with 2 arguments...

Answer (score 1):

Your list (`a`) is only created when you call the function. So it is not created unless you call the function once, try calling the function with another variable and then `a`